# Getting redirect to phantom page /user/register/thankyou

Tags: uri, redirection

In Drupal 8, I created a page with the path alias `/user/register/thankyou` to redirect users to after registration.  Later, I changed the url of this page to simply be `/register/user/thankyou`.  I have the **Redirect** module enabled, so I deleted the redirect from `/user/register/thankyou` to `/thankyou/registration`.

However, now, when I go to `/user/register`, I am automatically redirected to `/user/register/thankyou`, which results in a "page not found" error.

So, somehow, there is still a "ghost" redirect in my system, although the redirect module page shows that there are no redirects on the site, and I double-checked the page with the alias `/thankyou/registration`, which has the correct alias.

I uninstalled the redirect module but the redirect persists.

The redirect occurs when I type the URL to the user register page manually (`www.example.com/user/register`) and when I click the "register account" link.

I opened up the database in MySQL workbench and I see nothing strange in the `router` table or the `url_alias` table; my alias to `/register/user/thankyou` exists but I cannot find the `/user/register/thankyou` alias anywhere (although this is where `/user/register` is being redirected).

How do I fix this redirect error?

I tried three different browsers and cloned the site from production to my local environment; in all cases, I have this issue.

Comment: Obvious question but caches are all cleared? Have you tried cache busting that url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake... it turns out I had a redirect in a custom module that I had been using for testing.

`grep` the custom modules directory for `user/register` saved the day...